# wagtail browsing child pages issue

Tags: wagtail

getting message

```
Only pages of type "International investment sector page" may be chosen for this field. Search results will exclude pages of other types.
```

for our pages we have

```
class InternationalInvestmentSubSectorPage(
    panels.InternationalInvestmentSubSectorPagePanels,
    BaseInternationalPage,
):
    parent_page_types = ['great_international.InternationalInvestmentSectorPage']


class InternationalInvestmentSectorPage(
    panels.InternationalInvestmentSectorPagePanels,
    BaseInternationalPage,
):
    parent_page_types = ['great_international.InternationalTopicLandingPage']
    subpage_types = ['great_international.InternationalInvestmentSubSectorPage']
```

I was not expecting this message ?

Comment: Where are you getting that message, exactly?

Comment: in the UI, comes from browser.html based on page_type_string != wagtailcore.page

Comment: page_type_string is actually 'great_international.internationalinvestmentsectorpage'

Comment: Right, but what are you doing in the admin interface when that message comes up? For example, getting that message when moving a page, and getting that message when inserting a link to a page, are totally different scenarios, and without that context it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Hard to explain without seeing UI but our user is selecting change sector from page and expecting to see sub sectors as its a child but not

Comment: "change sector" is not a concept that exists in Wagtail itself, so without any details of how that's implemented, I can't really help any further.